# Where to get the source code of castle project

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-activerecord, castle-monorail, castle

The castle project is open source. I am wondering where to get its source code. I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it [here](http://www.castleproject.org/git.html)

**EDIT**

Above link is no longer valid. Was at the time when question was answered beg. of 2011. Code is now hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/castleproject

Comment: can I get the source code for the specific version, like 2.5.2

Comment: Yes, some versions seem to be tagged.
Look at the 'switch tags'. 2.5.2, 2.5.1 are tagged.
https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Core#

Comment: all the recent versions are tagged

Comment: @Justin link was valid when I answered over a year ago. They must have changed it in the meantime. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where it was about a year ago, but now all the castle projects code is in Github.

https://github.com/castleproject

Answer (score 2):

Is this it? http://www.castleproject.org/git.html